# Wordpress Plugin: How to change CSS based on user input

Tags: css, wordpress

I've created a plugin for Wordpress that display's a bunch of information in a table.
I have an options page where you can enter a color for odd, and even rows. The options page saves the user input fine. But I'm not sure how to update the CSS with the user input.
This is what I have, it technically works, but when I place any other widget in my sidebar, all the options of that widget disappears. So I'm obviously doing something wrong. There must be a better way.

```
ob_start();

function change_row_color(){
    global $odd;
    global $even;

    if(!get_option('gfd_rc_odd')){
        $odd   = "eee";
    }else{
        $odd = esc_attr(get_option('gfd_rc_odd'));
    }
    if(!get_option('gfd_rc_even')){
        $even   = "fff";
    }else{
        $even = esc_attr(get_option('gfd_rc_even'));
    }
    ?>

<style type="text/css">
#stockchart tr:nth-child(odd){ 
    background-color:#<?php echo $odd; ?>;
}
#stockchart tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#<?php echo $even; ?>; 
}
</style>

<?php
}
change_row_color();
```

Comment: The problem is most likely in your widget code , and not in this code you posted . and BTW - the widgets settings are supposed to be clean on every widget instancing..Can you elaborate on the "disappearing" part - what widget´s settings are disappearing

Comment: So when I drag the Wordpress "text" widget over to the sidebar. the fields for "title" and "body" disappear, and all you see is "delete | close" and the Save button. It's very odd. When I commented out the script above, that problem went away. So that's why I thought it was the problem. I can put all my code into a JSFiddle. I'm sure it's messy as it's a school project and my first attempt at a plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/WGPfK/

Comment: Right . .something is very wrong with your widget , but I did not had enough time to debug it correctly . Try to seperate the widget code to a stand alone plugin and debug . also - there is no real reason to make a settings page for a widget ... Its only cluttering the UI

Comment: The plugin is for a class project, I only created a settings page to show that you "can" create one. I'll keep trying to figure out what I did wrong, but I haven't come up with anything yet.